Find the probability that it was really a rainy day
The probability that a particular day in the month of July is a rainy day is $\frac 3 4$. Two person whose credibility are $\frac 4 5$ and $\frac 2 3$, respectively, claim that $15$-th July was a rainy day. Find the probability that it was really a rainy day. $(\operatorname {Ans}=\frac{24}{25})$
There are similar questions in my textbook one of them above which asked.
Probability that $A$ speaks truth is $\frac 4 5$. A coin is tossed. $A$ reports that a head appears. Find the probability that actually there was head.
For this question the probability that it was actually a head ultimately means that $A$ speaks the truth so the answer is $\frac 4 5$ only (which matches with the answer in the textbook).
But for the first mentioned problem I'm not even able to proceed.

$~R~$ is the event that the particular day is rainy.  $~S~$ is the event that both people claim that it is rainy.  Then, by conditional probability $$p(~R ~| ~S ~) = \frac{p(~R \cap S ~)}{p(S)}.$$

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@user2661923 thankyou I got the answer with your hint , my mistake was that I was not able to frame the event S properly (I used the conditional probability formula again on the numerator then applied total probability theorem for the denominator)  (also could you please particularly mention what issue did you find in this post? There were not any expressions so I did not use any latex( I could only see a grammatical issue which I've fixed) )

In the protocol article that I linked to, go through the bullet points one by one, and identify those bullet points that you did not respond to.

$\underline{\mathtt{Hint}}$
Both are in agreement, so both are either telling the truth or lying.

 P(Rained and both telling truth): $\frac34\frac45\frac23 = \frac{24}{60}$


 P(Didn't rain and both lying): $\frac14\frac15\frac13 = \frac1{60}$


 Odds in favor of rain $= 24:1$


 Probability it rained $=\frac{24}{25}$

Having arrived at the answer, you should be able to couch it in appropriate symbols using conditional probability and total probability theorem.

Out of curiosity, what's the motivation behind the Burma Shave spoilers? :-)

@BrianTung: The idea is to  motivate OP to think for some time before stripping each layer.

I figured, but I thought I'd ask. (And also I like any opportunity to use the phrase "Burma Shave" haha.)

@BrianTung: Yea, I'll remember to use it if I come across such a case, a very apt phrase !

@trueblueanil So by default the statement it really rains on that day we should consider that it really rains on that day if both are telling the truth. And could you please elaborate a bit more on  "Both are in agreement, so both are either telling the truth or lying."  I didn't understand why is he above true ?

@Anonymous123: If both are saying the same thing for $\texttt{any}$ particular event, then either both are speaking the truth, or both are lying.

@trueblueanil Ok ,Thankyou

First person strengths the probabilty of rain by
$$\frac{\frac34\frac45}{\frac34\frac45+\frac14\frac15}=\frac{12}{13}.$$
Then, the second person strengths by
$$\frac{\frac23\frac{12}{13}}{\frac23\frac{12}{13}+\frac13\frac1{13}}=\frac{24}{25}.$$
